# Category opposite hom set

Tags: category-theory

What is the best elementary proof of the statement: if $f\colon x \rightarrow y$ and $c,x,y \in \mathcal{C}$ then

$$f^{op}_*\colon \mathcal{C}^{op}(c,y) \rightarrow \mathcal{C}^{op}(c,x) $$ is a bijection if and only if $$f^*\colon \mathcal{C}(y,c) \rightarrow \mathcal{C}(x,c) $$ is a bijection?

Here, for $h^{op}\colon c \rightarrow y$ we have $f^{op}_*(h^{op}) = f^{op}h^{op}$ and for $k\colon y \rightarrow c$ we have $f^*(k)=kf$.

I have a proof, but it is not a very clean argument, and I have seen that in Category Theory sometimes arguments are very clear and short. So I have doubts about my categorical thinking (I'm a beginner and I'm learning about duality) and I want to compare with yours.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, $f^*$ and $f_*^{op}$ are literally the same map.  We have $f^*(h)=hf$ and $f_*^{op}(h^{op})=f^{op}h^{op}=(hf)^{op}$.  But $g$ and $g^{op}$ are just two different names for the exact same thing, just considered as morphisms of different categories.  So $f^*$ and $f_*^{op}$ are literally the exact same map of sets (their domains and codomains are the same set, and they give the same output on all inputs).

(Or, if you define $g$ and $g^{op}$ to not be *literally* the same thing, then $f_*^{op}$ is obtained from $f^*$ by composing with bijections which swap $g$ and $g^{op}$.)

Comment: Just a follow-up on this answer. So $g$ and $g^{op}$ are exactly the same morphism, but $g$ lies in $Hom(x,y)$ in $\mathcal{C}$ and $g^{-1}$ lies in $Hom(y,x)$ in $\mathcal{C}^{op}$?